# Ruby(rails/sinatra) + EJB jar packaged to EAR on Torquebox

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, torquebox

I'm trying to wrap my head around torquebox deployment options. I have old application with well-separated core business logic (in jar archive: cdi, ebj and all that stuff). I'd like to write frontend for it in ruby (rails/sinatra) and deploy it on torquebox.

As far as I know I can put my ejb-jar into `lib/` directory of ruby app, but is there a way to package all that stuff into ear archive? I mean can I  have ejb module and ruby web module as a parts of ear application?

The only thing I found was https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TORQUE-85

Also what about classloaders? Are they isolated in torquebox per application?